# Eclipse - Java virtual machine launcher error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and for some reason after that I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA. When I try to run Eclipse it gives me that error

> Error: could not open C:\Program
>   files\java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg

In Java file I have few JRE files (`1.8.0_20` , `1.8.0_121` , `1.8.0_131`).
So I do have the JRE file but for some reasons it does not find they.
Maybe its the path or maybe I should download other file. 
I have tried to download again Eclipse and also JRE file but nothing did work. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: check `preferences`->`java`->`Installed JREs`

Comment: I cant open Eclipse. that error jumps when i try to open it

Comment: in the eclipse installation folder look into `eclipse.ini`. Most likely you have a `-vm` option set with the wrong path.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to set the correct path?

Comment: If you correctly installed Java at your system you can simply remove this option.